# Making ModelBuilder "Read only" for another user in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I created my model In ArcGIS and use it to run as a tool in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS and I want to give them my model to other people in my company to run it. As they are not into GIS and they don't know how to use it , I would like somehow to lock the model that they just could run it but they have no access to the model itself.

Answer (score 2):

[ESRI Documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/managing-tools-and-toolboxes/setting-read-only-permissions-on-toolboxes.htm) says to set the toolbox to read-only in Windows. (Link is to 10.3 documentation but I have to believe the same workflow applies for 10.2)

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. However, I tried it but there is no such a thing even though I have 10.4 Advanced.

Comment: The read-only property is a standard Windows OS property. All files have it. (The same is true if you're using Linux.)